# $_POST variable name is variable, how to retrieve?

Tags: php

Users of my website can generate a custom form. All the fields are saved in a database with a unique ID. When someone visits the form, the fields 'name' attribute is field*ID*, for example

```
<p>Your favorite band? <input type="text" name="field28"></p>
<p>Your Favorite color? <input type="text" name="field30"></p>
```

After submitting the form, I use php to validate the form, but I don't know retrieve the value of $_POST[field28] (or whatever number the field has).

```
<?
while($field = $query_formfields->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
 {
 $id = $field[id];

 //this doesn't work!!
 $user_input = $_POST[field$id];

 //validation comes here
 }
?>
```

If anybody can help me out, it's really appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add some quotes:

```
$user_input = $_POST["field$id"];
```

Answer (score 7):

I'd suggest taking advantage of PHP's array syntax for forms:

```
<input type="text' name="field[28]" />
```

You can access this in php with `$_GET['field'][28]`

Comment: Didn't know that, a much nicer solution, will use that for sure in next projects. At the moment, the front end of my website is already developed, with all kinds of jquery actions based on form field names, so changing the field names is a bit of a hassle. Any big disadvantages of using the code as suggested by Amber?

Comment: @Dirk Nope, nothing wrong with Amber's solution at all. You seem to be able to already target the specific name with your `$id` variable so you should be all set. If you didn't have `$id` my solution would allow you to loop over `$_POST['field']` like an array grabbing all the values.

Answer (score 4):

```
$user_input = $_POST['field'.$id];
```

Answer (score 3):

Remember that you are using a `string` for the first part of the `input` name, so try something like: `$user_input=$_POST['field'.$id];`.
Also, I would suggest calling them into an `array` to retrieve all data:

```
<?php
    $user_inputs=array();
    while($field=$query_formfields->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $id=$field['id'];
        $user_inputs[]=$_POST['field'.$id];
    }
?>
```